# Chance Agreement for Fleiss Kappa

Tags: reliability, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

In *Measuring nominal scale agreement among many raters*, where the authors define Fleiss kappa, the agreement by chance is defined as

[image]

where $p_j$ is defined as the proportion of ratings which were to the $j$th category.

Can someone explain how the authors arrived at this equation?

An additional reference for the equations can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleiss%27_kappa)

Answer (score 0):

Say two raters respond randomly, with probability of yes = 0.9 and probability of no = 0.1, we can put the results into this table.

```
      Yes    |   No  
Yes          |        |  0.9 
 No          |        |  0.1
---------------------------
Total   0.9  |   0.1  |  1.0
```

Best case (perfect agreement):

```
            R1 
R2     Yes   |   No  
Yes    0.9   |   0.0  |  0.9 
 No    0.0   |   0.1  |  0.1
---------------------------
Total   0.9  |   0.1  |  1.0
```

Worst case (max disagreement):

```
            R1 
 R2    Yes   |   No  
 Yes   0.81  |   0.09  |  0.9 
 No    0.09  |   0.01  |  0.1
---------------------------
Total   0.9  |   0.1   |  1.0
```

How much disagreement do we have in the worst case? 0.9^2 + 0.1^2 = 0.82

That's the formula.

Comment: The way I am thinking about it is to calculate the probability that any two raters randomly agree. Assuming the categories are mutually independent
$P(\textrm{random chance agreement of any pair}) = \sum_j P(\textrm{random chance agreement of any pair}) = \sum_j p_j \cdot p_j$
where $p_j$ is the probability of assigning the unit to category $j$.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense.